# Agrupar por data e receber total de registros de cada data e montar outra matriz

Tags: javascript

```
[ 
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx, yyy: "yyy },

]
```

Olá,
preciso pegar do array acima o total de registro de cada data e criar uma outra matriz de objetos contendo o próprio nome e total como valores de novas chaves por exemplo:

```
[{
        "a": "23-04",
        "b": 3
    }, {
        "a": "23-05",
        "b": 3
    },
    {
        "a": "23-06",
        "b": 5
    }
]
```

Pode ser com es6, map, reduce ou mesmo com lodash/undescore

Agradeço a quem puder mastigar isso pois to a 3 dias e não sai do jeito que preciso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois exemplos que parecem funcionar...

```js
var origem = [
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-04", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-05", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
    { data: "23-06", xxx: "xxx", yyy: "yyy" },
];

var result1 = Object.entries(origem.reduce((acc, o) => (acc[o.data] = (acc[o.data] || 0) + 1, acc), {}))
    .map(([a, b]) => ({ a, b }));


let counts = {};
origem.forEach(el => counts[el.data] = (counts[el.data] || 0) + 1);
var result2 = Object.entries(counts).map(([a, b]) => ({ a, b }));

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Para vc tenho certeza que foi apenas alguns minutos no teclado para ajudar uma desconhecida, para mim, foi um alívio que já sofria a 3 dias. Seu código não só parece funcionar: ele é perfeito para meu propósito e caiu como uma luva inclusive resolvendo as chaves a e b com map....Meu muito obrigada a vc meu querido!!!